# jOOQ - build UPDATE FROM psql query

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

How to build the following PSQL query to update multiple records using jOOQ 3.10.x?

```
UPDATE users 
SET name = s.name, city = s.city 
FROM users_staging s
WHERE users.id = s.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
UsersStaging s = USERS_STAGING.as("s");

DSL.using(configuration)
   .update(USERS)
   .set(USERS.NAME, s.NAME)
   .set(USERS.CITY, s.CITY)
   .from(s)
   .where(USERS.ID.eq(s.ID))
   .execute();
```